# Repository boundaries

Tags: .net, design-patterns

Assuming that application has Business Objects library within repositories interfaces, implementation library and BLL (BPL), how do you decide what needs to be coupled with repository and what goes directly to BPL

**BOs.dll**
*ISomeObjectRepository.cs*

```
public interface ISomeObjectRepository:  
IRepository<SomeObject>, ILazyFetchingRepository<SomeObject>  
{  
      SomeObject GetSomeObjectByWeirdFields(IDictionary<string, object> weirdFields);  
}
```

**Repositories.dll**
*SomeObjectRepository.cs*

```
public sealed class SomeObjectRepository:  
BaseRepository<SomeObject>, ISomeObjectRepository  
{  
     public SomeObject GetSomeObjectByWeirdFields(IDictionary<string, object> weirdFields){  
         throw new NotImplementedException();  
        }  
}
```

**BPL.dll**
*SomeObjectService.cs*

```
public static class SomeObjectService:  
{  
     public static SomeObject GetSomeObjectByWeirdFields(IDictionary<string, object> weirdFields){  
           throw new NotImplementedException();  
     }  
}
```

So the question really is, whose responsibility is GetSomeObjectByWeirdFields implementation? Any guides to patterns are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The repository interface exist in the domain layer (business layer) as you mentioned, that defines the contract that abstracts the repository in the domain model.

The service layer depends on the abstraction of the repository (ISomeObjectRepository) and know nothing about the concrete implementation.

The answer of your question to where to implement the concrete repository, it shall be defined in a lower layer which could be called Data Access Layer, or Technical Service Layer, or Persistence Layer, whatever you call it the important thing is that you implement it in a different component, this component could be replaced without affecting all other layer nor affecting the repository interface. for example you can implement you repositories using NHibernate, you can later decide to replace it with Entity Framework implementation, Ado, or even xml files.

The thing is that concrete implementation of repository should be separated in another component belong to technical services or data access.

check http://sellandbuy.codeplex.com/ to get a sample implementation of repository using NHibernate in a separate layer.